# check font is loaded with document.fonts.check and it always return true

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to check if certain font is loaded with the [`FontFaceSet#check()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check) API but it always returns `true` to me, no matter what random stuff I put.
I tried in both Chrome and Safari, with the same result.
Here are the results in my console:
[image: Screenchot of a web page with the dev-tools opened showing various attempts to use document.fonts.check() with seemingly non existant font values, like "1px tst", but returning true nonetheless]

Am I using this API wrongly?

I tried to google this issue and the API usage without any luck.
I expected `document.fonts.check()` would `false` if the font doesn't exist / is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the expected behavior, `FontFaceSet` cannot be used to determine if a font is available or not.

The description from the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check) you linked to says

> The `check()` method of the `FontFaceSet` returns `true` if you can render some text using the given font specification without attempting to use any fonts in this `FontFaceSet` that are not yet fully loaded.

And that's all it does: It will tell you if when rendering the text the browser will have to load one of the fonts that are already registered in the `FontFaceSet` or not.
In the case of font-families that haven't been registered in the `FontFaceSet`, the browser will not load any new font because that font doesn't exists to begin with, and thus `.check()` will return `true`.

The MDN article even has [a paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check#nonexistent_fonts) about that:

> #### Nonexistent fonts
>
> If we specify a font that is not in the `FontFaceSet` and is not a system font, `check()` returns `true`, because in this situation we will not rely on any fonts from the set: